# Windows VPN Client - Dial more than 2 concurrent connections

Tags: windows, vpn

I frequently need to dial multiple VPN connections to different isolated sites. I would like to have multiple connections active concurrently, but Windows (10 and 11) seems to limit the number of active connections to 2. Whenever I try to dial a third connection, I get an error saying "The modem is already in use". It happens for any combination of connections. How do I increase the two connections limit? All the VPN connections are IKEv2-based and the VPN client is the one built into Windows.

Answer (score -1):

For every VPN connection you do need a separate network interface. Depending on the VPN client/solution it allows you configure additional interfaces. A lot of them don't.

However, as soon as you start using multiple VPN connections at the same time you have to be aware of your local routing to get them working properly together.
If different VPN destinations use the same IP ranges, routing could become very challenging and conflicts could appear with weird results.

A simple solution would be to use each VPN on individual VMs. Cant tell if this is viable in your case.

Comment: The VPN client is the one built into Windows, and yes it creates an interface pr connection. I am aware of the potential routing issues with multiple connections. For these connections, there is no routing issue, and the problem I am describing happens before the tunnel is established. I am specifically looking to have multiple connections dialed from a single workstation, thus a solution with multiple VMs is not viable in this case.